# Text file give error - Transfer error: No such file or directory - DDMS

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pull my text file which the name of the file was programmed according to the title of an article which is `MACC is on the right track, let’s hope it will go all the way.txt` but on pull it gives me this error :

```
[2016-08-29 11:59:06 - ddms] transfer error: No such file or directory
[2016-08-29 11:59:06] Failed to pull selection: No such file or directory
```

When I try to delete

```
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:206)
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:707)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:344)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

my source code

```
public void storeHTML(Context context, ArrayList<String> storeHTML) {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "voicethenews");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, storeHTML.get(0) + ".txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

        for(int i = 1; i < storeHTML.size(); i++) {

            //bufferedWriter.newLine();
            writer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + storeHTML.get(i));

        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've searched high and low for the answer put still didn't manage to solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this code:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/SOME_DIRECTORY"
```